# How to prove the pseudorandomness of CryptoPAn

Tags: aes, block-cipher, pseudo-random-generator

in my cryptography course, we are learning about pseudo randomness and the prefix-preserving function known as CryptoPAn invented in 2002. It is said that the scheme is highly insecure. So in that case, i am leaning towards disproving the pseudorandomness of cryptoPAn. But i am struggling to put it into words.

for your kind information, this is crpytopan : https://handwiki.org/wiki/Crypto-PAn

Answer (score 1):

Since you're still learning, I would give you an answer; however consider the encryption of the IP addresses 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2; how would those two ciphertexts be related?  How could you use that as a distinguisher from a random permutation?